# Zenject inject plain class into Monobehaviour

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, zenject

I'm trying to inject plain C# class into Mobobehaviour, but an "Unable to resolve 'HeightSystem' while building object with type 'UserDirijible'. Object graph: UserDirijible" exception is thrown.

```
namespace Systems {
    public class HeightSystem
    {
...
}
```

```
using Zenject;

namespace Systems {
    public class HeightSystemInstaller : MonoInstaller<HeightSystemInstaller>
{
    public override void InstallBindings()
    {
        Container.BindInstance<HeightSystem>(new HeightSystem()).AsSingle();
    }
}
}
```

```
//UserDirijible.cs
[Inject]
public Systems.HeightSystem heightSystem;
```

HeightSystemInstaller is attached to empty object in scene. What is may cause this error? Previously, Monobehaviour classes injection was work fine. I was mostly working with Dagger 2 and till now can not find the piece of documentation about injection plain C# classes into Monobehaviours

Comment: Is your installer referenced by a context? (Scene context or GameObject context, attached to the gameObject holding the `UserDirijible` component

Comment: Thanks, that was cause of error. I forgot about this

Answer (score 3):

Injected object was not attached to Scene context